# FileNotFoundException with Universal Image Loader on Android 7+

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, universal-image-loader, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I use `Universal Image Loader` for image loading inside our android app. It works well with usual links, however, since our API has changed, now this link doesn't work: https://img.anews.com?url=https://img.anews.com/media/posts/images/20180419/89413447.jpg&w=1080&h=735

This is the error log:

```
04-19 11:08:11.717 16501-16779/anews.com E/ImageLoader: https://img.anews.com?url=https://img.anews.com/media/posts/images/20180419/89413447.jpg&w=1080&h=735
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://img.anews.com?url=https://img.anews.com/media/posts/images/20180419/89413447.jpg&w=1080&h=735
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:124)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:98)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:74)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:265)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:238)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I seem to have this problem only on Android 7+. On all previous versions, images load just fine. Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` suggests that you are getting a 404 response. Are you seeing that on the server? You might also try URL-encoding the `url` parameter and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare - when I click on this URL, I see the image in a browser. Also, it works on older Android versions. I don't seem to get 404. Can you tell a bit more about the URL-encoding fix?

Comment: "I don't seem to get 404" -- well, you might be from this test device that is throwing the `FileNotFoundException`, which is why I suggested checking the server (e.g., examining server logs). "Can you tell a bit more about the URL-encoding fix?" -- technically, [your URL is invalid](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/).

Comment: @CommonsWare — You’ve been right about the 404. Strangely though, I’ve tested the app on different devices. It gets 200 on Android 4,5,6 and 8. It gets 404 only on Android 7. Also the request URL is wrong on Android 7. How can it be possible, what’s wrong with Android 7?